# Reusing Haskell code in multiple projects

Tags: git, haskell, code-reuse

There are a few modules I have written that I often want to copy into other projects to reuse the code. However, if I simply copy the modules, then if I ever want to improve them, I would have to update all of the copies in the various git repositories for the projects that use them.

It seems like I should create some sort of library. How can I set up my projects such that I only need to update these modules once, and all of the repositories that depend on them will have access to the newest version?

Comment: What are you using to build your code? Stack or Cabal?

Comment: You could make links (if your file system supports that) to the files, such that updating it on one place, means that it updated on other places as well.

Comment: @arrowd Cabal, though that could change I guess

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I guess, but that would still require committing the changes in each repository, which isn't ideal (maybe unavoidable though, I don't know).

Comment: In case of Cabal you can create cabal sandboxes and do `cabal sandbox add-source` to all of your libraries.

Comment: @arrowd sandboxes are largely obsolete with the advent of [Nix-style builds](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/). I wouldn't worry learning them as a beginner; even old-style global installs _usually_ work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundle the modules in packages (or possibly make single-module-packages). If you haven't done that before, [read the Cabal user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#developing-packages). Each package, like any other code, should be under version control (git, darcs, whatever) though this isn't strictly speaking necessary for your need.

Say you have one such package, `foo`, containing the modules `Common.Foo` and `Common.Foo.Types`, i.e. you have a folder containing `Common/Foo.hs` and `Common/Foo/Types.hs` and a `foo.cabal` file with `exposed-modules: Common.Foo Common.Foo.Types`.

The projects in which you want to *use* `Common.Foo` should then also be cabal packages and, apart from the obvious `import Common.Foo` in the Haskell source files, should have a `.cabal` file with `build-depends: foo`.

Then, whenever you've changed the modules of the `foo` package, you can just type `cabal install --force-reinstalls`<sup>†</sup> (from inside `foo`s directory). This will update the local package registry, and when you then `cabal configure` and `cabal build` another project using `foo`, it will have access to the changes.

Consider also actually [publishing your package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/upload) (of course, make sure to actually give it a *clear, descriptive* name!), then you won't even have to worry about getting the source and compiling when you switch to another machine – cabal can do that for you.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The `--force-reinstalls` is only necessary after you've also `install`ed one of the packages that depend on `foo`. After reinstalling `foo`, you *must* then also rebuild these – that's a bit of a flaw in the way cabal-install registers installs. This will [become unnecessary](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/) in the future.</sub>

Comment: So the dependent package will be able to find `foo` because it is entered into this "local package registry"?

Comment: C o r r e c t .

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake `stack` is a great tool for ensuring reproducable builds, but I could never see much point in using it for local hacking. Especially the Nix-style `cabal new-build` doesn't really leave anything to be desired that stack could fill, IMO. That said, if you add an answer focusing on how this can be done with Stack, it's certainly a worthwhile addition.

Comment: Well, it's much easier to add local dependencies with `stack` in my experience, which is why I thought of it.

Comment: Done. I'll look into `new-build` though.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @leftroundabout's excellent answer, there is another way of adding local dependencies using `stack` by adding the path to your `stack.yaml`:

```
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
- location: path/to/my/incredible/haskell/goodies
- location:
    git: url/to/my/fp/repository
    commit: [commit-hash]
  extra-dep: true
[etc., etc.]
```

Assuming you haven't heard of this tool already (which *mostly* resolves the infamous cabal-hell problem), I highly recommend checking it out.